# Styling a button on Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a button as part of a Xamarin Forms custom renderer. I can style the button as I wish on iOS and Android in code without an issue and for the most part, can do the same on Windows Phone 8.

I'm having a problem though with including an image on a button with text next to it and altering the border on the button so it is rounded. I've found plenty of examples using XAML, but not in pure C#.

Currently, the custom renderer on Windows Phone looks like this

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NewButton), typeof(NewButtonRenderer))]
namespace WinPhone
{
class NewButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Button> e)
{
 base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control != null)
        {
            Control.ApplyTemplate();

            var border = new Border
            {
                CornerRadius = new System.Windows.CornerRadius(10),
            };

            Control.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
            Control.Background = new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(255, 130, 186, 132));
            Control.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(255,45,176,51)) ;
            Control.BorderThickness = new System.Windows.Thickness(0.8);
             }
         }
    }
}
```

I have a Border set up, but can't find a way to add it (and secondary to this, if I have the background, border brush and border thickness in the Border object, does it have the same effect as applying directly to the control?), nor a way of creating an image button with an image in my Images directory.

Is what I'm trying to do correct or am I missing a piece of the jigsaw? I'm doing this in pure C# for a specific reason.

Comment: Out of sheer curiosity what is the reason for pure c#? I think that to place an image on a button in c# you can create the image with the source you want and asign that image as Button.Content

Comment: I'm creating a cross platform UI system that takes an XML file which contains the object type and renders that on screen with given parameters. For example I would have <uiType>Button <color>ARGB color</color><image>Ball.png</image><hasEvents>True</hasEvents><eventsID>GUID</eventsID></uiType> - to keep this all simple, rather than having XAML to control the objects on one platform and pure code on the other two, I have pure code on all 3 - just helps keep things easy for me.

Comment: Any ideas on the border style?